# Elementor, Nav Menu, Submenu - Gaps (?) between submenu items and border

Tags: wordpress, menu, elementor, submenu

I am currently helping out with the company website, which is constructed using Elementor in WordPress. We have a header menu, with some menu items expanding to show a submenu, and the items have a 1px high divider between them, but for *some* of the items, there's a thin black line. There's also this thin black line between the subitems and the border of the entire submenu.

[Here's how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxMix.png) (I obviously replaced the submenu items to not have this recognised, but that is unrelated to the issue.)
The red rectangles point to the issue, while the blue one points to what I want it to look like.

I tried to tweak the border, divider, and shadow settings for the submenu, but nothing came through. It looks like a visual bug, so I don't expect this to be solved with Elementor itself, but maybe with some custom CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with custom `border: 0 solid !important` in the CSS for the menu items

**Update:**
`border-bottom: 1px solid YOUR-COLOR !important`

Comment: This worked to some extent, and it is definitely an improvement, but it removed the dividers between the submenu items.

Comment: Ok then please have a look my update above in the response

Comment: Not quite, I still had a line remaining. Making it 2px 'solved' it, but it is of course thicker than intended. But honestly, I'm fine with it. It might be of interest to solve this better, but for my part, I consider it solved.
Thanks!